# Linux server disappearing from network

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ethernet

I have an Ubuntu 16.04.2 server I've recently setup at home. I was doing checkout and install using wireless. I was running so well that I decided it was time to move off to the basement, connect it via ethernet, and start using it.

But I couldn't keep the ethernet running. I would be connected to it and the network would just go away, only to usually come back in a minute or so. I ran a ping on the server while connected and I can see it go from good, to timeout, to back on, with no discernible pattern. I tried changing cables - no change. I read about a kernel bug with small MTUs, so I changed mine to 8192 - no change. My machine has an on-board ethernet driver using the apparently infamous r8169 driver. I swapped that driver for the r8168 - no change. I bought a NIC and installed that - no change. Unfortunately, the NIC also used the realtek driver, so I bought a USB3 Ethernet adapter - no change. Throughout all of this, the wireless runs fine more or less. It is slightly flaky with avahi, but otherwise useable. I'm pretty sure I tried to disable avahi too, but I'm starting to lose track of things.

Now I'm checking the machine while it is supposedly not responding to pings. Any outgoing request (over ethernet) via TCP or ping immediately restores the machine to the network. Then it will resume its bad behaviour after a few seconds/minutes. I've searched in vain for any evidence of any problem in log files.

Could this be a problem with my CGN3ROG cable model's ethernet ports? At this point, the only thing I can think of doing is some kind of keep alive setting or script. That is such a crude hack though.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this old chestnut, disabling IPV6:

Back up /etc/systctl.conf and then add these lines to the end:

net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1

Run 'sudo sysctl -p' to make sure your changes kept, then restart networking by running 'systemctl restart networking'

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I added those lines and restarted. Unfortunately, no change. My outgoing ping script is working, but I only ping out once every 5 seconds. It limits the drop outs to 4 seconds. But that is still an annoying lag in the terminal.